# Smoothing out surfaces obtained through displacement modifier

Tags: texturing, subdivision-surface, displacement, procedural

I'm inspecting ways to smooth things correctly in Blender. I've created this structure out of a cube and displacement modifiers applied to every side. As you can see, results bear some grid artifacts:

[image]

My question: is there a way of smoothing that out of the usual subsurf modifier? 
I've used procedural textures over vertex groups to create displacement.
Maybe there is a way to obtain smoother geometry by using finer textures in the beginning...
I could resort to some smooth modifier, but there are three of them and the difference is not really clear to me...
Thank you in advance.

[the .blend file](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1HiIioz7GrmJ3gQpeOF5LOlh2mq5jejcd)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seeing nobody answering, I'll post something myself:

[image]

Obviously, used subsurf.
I'll be checking in other ways when I have some more time...